# Programmatically setting "Span" color doesn't work in FormattedString for a Label in NativeScript Vue

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to use the programmatic way of setting the Label text using FormattedString as I need to have different text colors in the output text.

I am trying the change the span's foreground color but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know any other way of achieving the same or can point out what am I missing here?

Please find the [Playground with the code](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=U5EbLY&v=2).

Code Snippet:

```
createFormattedString(stringsToFormat) {
stringsToFormat = stringsToFormat ?
    stringsToFormat :
    [{
            text: "It's going to be ",
            type: "normal"
        },
        {
            text: "sunny",
            type: "orange"
        },
        {
            text: " today!",
            type: "normal"
        }
    ];

const formattedString = require("text/formatted-string");
const formattedSpan = require("text/span");
const ColorModule = require("tns-core-modules/color");
let fstringToSend = new formattedString.FormattedString();

stringsToFormat.forEach((currentStrFragment, idx) => {
    let fspan = new formattedSpan.Span();
    fspan.text = currentStrFragment.text;
    fspan.color = new ColorModule.Color(
        "#FFFFFF");
    switch (currentStrFragment.type) {
        case "normal":
            //fspan.color = "black";
            break;
        case "orange":
            console.log("ORANGE setting anything");

            // fspan.class = "orange-text";
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Not setting anything");
            break;
    }
    fstringToSend.spans.push(fspan);
});
return fstringToSend;
}
```

Screenshot of output: (The text is still in black):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for setting the formattedText programmatically:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=U5EbLY&v=3

Any other ways are welcome!